# Azure CLI throws 'Invalid IPv6 URL' and failes when trying to login

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Installed Azure CLI 2.28 on a machine, when trying to use it it always throws 'Invalid IPv6 URL'
When trying AZ login with or without --use-device-code, it failes with the following traceback.

```
az login --use-device-code
Invalid IPv6 URL
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
Invalid IPv6 URL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py", line 152, in login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 208, in find_subscriptions_on_login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 936, in find_through_interactive_flow
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/authentication_context.py", line 284, in acquire_user_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 65, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 45, in _get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/oauth2_client.py", line 298, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 373, in urlparse
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 464, in urlsplit
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
```

Having reinstalled azure-cli and having looked for any solutions, I have found nothing. Any idea?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBWca.png)

Edit: --debug output

```
az login --debug --use-device-code
Invalid IPv6 URL
cli.knack.cli: Command arguments: ['login', '--debug', '--use-device-code']
cli.knack.cli: __init__ debug log:
Enable color in terminal.
Init colorama.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PreExecute []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandParser.OnGlobalArgumentsCreate [<function CLILogging.on_global_arguments at 0x03634148>, <function OutputProducer.on_global_arguments at 0x0379FFA0>, <function CLIQuery.on_global_arguments at 0x037C5BB0>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableCreate []
cli.azure.cli.core: Modules found from index for 'login': ['azure.cli.command_modules.profile']
cli.azure.cli.core: Loading command modules:
cli.azure.cli.core: Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands
cli.azure.cli.core: profile                   0.005         2         9
cli.azure.cli.core: Total (1)                 0.005         2         9
cli.azure.cli.core: Loaded 2 groups, 9 commands.
cli.azure.cli.core: Found a match in the command table.
cli.azure.cli.core: Raw command  : login
cli.azure.cli.core: Command table: login
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableTruncate [<function AzCliLogging.init_command_file_logging at 0x03B63070>]
cli.azure.cli.core.azlogging: metadata file logging enabled - writing logs to 'C:\Users\jm4484_a\.azure\commands\2021-09-27.14-37-13.login.10728.log'.
az_command_data_logger: command args: login --debug --use-device-code
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreArgumentLoad [<function register_global_subscription_argument.<locals>.add_subscription_parameter at 0x03E2EA90>, <function register_global_query_examples_argument.<locals>.register_query_examples at 0x040AFBB0>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostArgumentLoad []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostCommandTableCreate [<function register_ids_argument.<locals>.add_ids_arguments at 0x040AFC40>, <function register_cache_arguments.<locals>.add_cache_arguments at 0x040AFCD0>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnCommandTableLoaded []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreParseArgs []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostParseArgs [<function OutputProducer.handle_output_argument at 0x037B1028>, <function CLIQuery.handle_query_parameter at 0x037C5BF8>, <function register_global_query_examples_argument.<locals>.handle_example_parameter at 0x03BA52
20>, <function register_ids_argument.<locals>.parse_ids_arguments at 0x040AFEC8>]
cli.azure.cli.core._profile: 'C:\Users\jm4484_a\.azure\accessTokens.json' is not a file or doesn't exist.
adal-python: 8ee67c4f-799a-49bb-be4e-0b37c3df8803 - Authority:Performing instance discovery: ...
adal-python: 8ee67c4f-799a-49bb-be4e-0b37c3df8803 - Authority:Performing static instance discovery
adal-python: 8ee67c4f-799a-49bb-be4e-0b37c3df8803 - Authority:Authority validated via static instance discovery
adal-python: 8ee67c4f-799a-49bb-be4e-0b37c3df8803 - CodeRequest:Getting user code info.
adal-python: 8ee67c4f-799a-49bb-be4e-0b37c3df8803 - OAuth2Client:Get Device Code request failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/oauth2_client.py", line 298, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 373, in urlparse
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 464, in urlsplit
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py", line 152, in login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 208, in find_subscriptions_on_login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 936, in find_through_interactive_flow
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/authentication_context.py", line 284, in acquire_user_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 65, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 45, in _get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/oauth2_client.py", line 298, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 373, in urlparse
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 464, in urlsplit
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
az_command_data_logger: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Invalid IPv6 URL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py", line 152, in login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 208, in find_subscriptions_on_login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 936, in find_through_interactive_flow
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/authentication_context.py", line 284, in acquire_user_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 65, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 45, in _get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/oauth2_client.py", line 298, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 373, in urlparse
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 464, in urlsplit
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
az_command_data_logger: Invalid IPv6 URL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py", line 152, in login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 208, in find_subscriptions_on_login
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 936, in find_through_interactive_flow
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/authentication_context.py", line 284, in acquire_user_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 65, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/code_request.py", line 45, in _get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\adal/oauth2_client.py", line 298, in get_user_code_info
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\requests/utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 373, in urlparse
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 464, in urlsplit
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x03B63190>]
az_command_data_logger: exit code: 1
cli.__main__: Command ran in 2.794 seconds (init: 0.450, invoke: 2.344)
telemetry.save: Save telemetry record of length 5817 in cache
telemetry.check: Returns Positive.
telemetry.main: Begin creating telemetry upload process.
telemetry.process: Creating upload process: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\azure\cli\telemetry\__init__.pyc C:\Users\jm4484_a\.azure"
telemetry.process: Return from creating process
telemetry.main: Finish creating telemetry upload process.
```

Comment: It wasn't able to trace your host IPv6 address. Try just disabling IPv6 on the host network interface

Comment: I had already tried that. I now double checked that there is no Ipv6 on the NIC's enabled and rebooted the machine. I also reinstalled the cli, sadly, to no avail

Comment: @JanMcke Could you please run the command with `--debug` and share the relevant output?

Comment: @JanMcke Also, have you tried installing via the MSI?

Comment: Was installed via the MSI, yes.

Comment: `--debug` output added to main post

Comment: @JanMcke Couldn't reproduce this at my end. I also notice `OAuth2Client:Get Device Code request failed` in the debug logs. Please report this issue here: [Azure/azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=Bug_report.md&title=)